# Spawning Threads from a Servlet request

Tags: java, json, multithreading, servlets

There is a REST type web service that is managed by a servlet.

It retrieves about 1000 products and their spcifications from a database. 
This database query is fast.
And then the web service loops over this 1000 entries and for each product spec, it encodes it into a JSON string. Each JSON encoding takes abour 10 ms. So going through the 1000 products takes 10ms x 1000 = 10  seconds. So the web service response is slow. More than 10 seconds.

I was wondering if it is possible to make this processing concurrent as the formating of each product specs into a JSON string is completely independent from one product to the next. So in theory, if I created a pool of say 4 threads, I could give each thread 250 product specs and reformat to JSON concurrently, and reduce the processing time by nearly 4.

How does this work in practice in a servlet context? Can I spawn a Thread pool from a Servlet or from a POJO used by a Servlet? Since Servlet containers such as Jetty are already multithreaded, does this cause a conflict?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> How does this work in practice in a servlet context?

It really depends on your workload.  If you're serving many of these kind of request concurrently, you'll see very little gain.

But if your server is handling maybe ten queries each minute, then sure, make all these cores work out.

But keep in mind that you're allocating quite a bit of extra resources for each client, so you're actually trading better performance for lower scalability.

> Can I spawn a Thread pool from a Servlet or from a POJO used by a
>   Servlet?

Yes, absolutely. You don't want to mess around with threads when using EJBs, but's absolutely OK to do it with servlets.

> Since Servlet containers such as Jetty are already multithreaded, does
>   this cause a conflict?

Nope, not at all (but see my concerns above). Most web-servers are highly threaded because most of those threads are I/O bound, spoon-feeding stuff to clients - With non-blocking/event-driven IO, the number of threads needed is actually WAY lower.

Comment: @Dan, isn't this a problem of time-to-first-byte? If you're waiting for the entire dataset to be marshalled to JSON, your requests will wait for quite a bit before seeing the results flowing.

Answer (score 0):

A web service could be fine at 10 seconds IF it means being fair on the server usage to all other requesters. Otherwise, sure, concurrent (limit threads of course).

This is a perfect job for a ForkJoinPool (java7).

FYI, I would seriously consider jvm profiling this 10ms jason encoding... seems incredibly long.